# Display a text if element not shown in PHP

Tags: php

I have a code in PHP that displays icons of social medias. But when the user didn't fill them, they don't show up. Which is great but I would like to encourage them to fill it up with a text/link.

Here is the code :

```
<?php
    add_filter( "buddyboss_get_user_social_array", "buddyboss_user_social_remove_disabled" ); //remove disabled.

    //Allow users to display their social media links in their profiles.
    $profile_social_media_links_switch = boss_get_option( 'profile_social_media_links_switch' );
    if ( ! empty( $profile_social_media_links_switch ) ):
    $social_profiles = (array)boss_get_option( 'profile_social_media_links' );

    foreach ( $social_profiles as $social  ):

        if ( empty( $social['title'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $social_key                 = sanitize_title( $social['title'] );
        $background_image_style     = '';
        $icon_url                   = $social['thumb'];
        $url                        = buddyboss_get_user_social( bp_displayed_user_id(), $social_key ); //Get user social link

        //Set profile icon
        if ( ! empty ( $icon_url) ) {
            $background_image_style = "background-image: url($icon_url);  background-size: cover;";
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ( !empty( $url ) ): ?>
            <a class="btn" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $social['title'] ); ?>" target="_blank"><i style="<?php echo $background_image_style ?>" class="alt-social-icon alt-<?php echo empty( $background_image_style ) ? $social_key : ''; ?>"></i> </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>

</div>
```

How to add this text : Display your Social Profiles here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I caught the main goal, it is necessary to display the text `Display your Social Profiles here...` in case of no social_profiles.

I check on empty both `$profile_social_media_links_switch` and `$social_profiles`. If any of them is empty then show your desired text

Try this code:

```
<?php
add_filter( "buddyboss_get_user_social_array", "buddyboss_user_social_remove_disabled" ); //remove disabled.

//Allow users to display their social media links in their profiles.
$profile_social_media_links_switch = boss_get_option( 'profile_social_media_links_switch' );
if ( ! empty( $profile_social_media_links_switch ) ) {
    $social_profiles = (array)boss_get_option('profile_social_media_links');

    if (!empty($social_profiles)) {
        foreach ($social_profiles as $social) {
            if (empty($social['title'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $social_key = sanitize_title($social['title']);
            $background_image_style = '';
            $icon_url = $social['thumb'];
            $url = buddyboss_get_user_social(bp_displayed_user_id(), $social_key); //Get user social link

            //Set profile icon
            if (!empty ($icon_url)) {
                $background_image_style = "background-image: url($icon_url);  background-size: cover;";
            }

            if (!empty($url)) { ?>
                <a class="btn" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($social['title']); ?>"
                   target="_blank"><i
                        style="<?php echo $background_image_style ?>"
                        class="alt-social-icon alt-<?php echo empty($background_image_style) ? $social_key : ''; ?>"></i>
                </a>
            <?php
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Display your Social Profiles here...';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Display your Social Profiles here...';
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer ! 
It is not displaying any error but it is not working either :( Maybe another solution ?

Comment: I can't offer another solution based on this code. If it run there should be some output (icons, or this line `Display ...`)

Comment: I am never lucky, the simplest code never works for me :P thank you anyway